# Hyperlink the question/answer link in review-ban message

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, review-suspension

I reviewed an answer on Low Quality Posts queue wrongly.

So, reviewing another post showed a pop up warning about it with question link as shown in below image (shown with freehand circle):

[image]
[image]

it will be more helpful if the link in pop up is hyperlinked.

Comment: This isn't a bad idea, but these manual suspensions aren't *so* common that it's a terribly high priority, I'd think.

Answer (score 13):

This is a good idea.

However, it should be noted that that link is only the link to one bad review decision. There are probably more. A review suspension is usually the result of several bad reviews.
So it's not just one bad review that the reviewer should consider; they should re-consider their entire recent reviewing history.

For this reason, we should not just provide a direct link to one bad review. We should show a few recent bad reviews, if known. And then ask the reviewer to compare their reviewing to [What are the guidelines for reviewing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155538/168333) on MSE.
I believe that, if the reviewer decides to continue reviewing after their supsension ends, this will benefit them more than just a link to one bad review.

Comment: It appears that the automated review messages are hyperlinking the review in question... putting a link in a manual review ban doesn't get automatically hyperlinked... not sure if the messages support markdown syntax, but if they do, I guess mods will just have to remember to use it...

Comment: Showing recent bad reviews and comparing reviews to guideline for reviewing is actually good idea.